# Parse Server - Local Datastore in Parse-SDK-dotNET

Tags: xamarin.forms, parse-server

I started recently using **Parse Server** in my **Xamarin.Forms** application using the DotNet version of their SDK.

I tried to cache some objects or queries, but surprisingly, The ParseObject in DotNetSDK doesn't have a method pinInBackground like in the Android version of the SDK : https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#local-datastore

And I couldn't find anythink about Opbject Caching or local datastore in the DotNet version of Documentation.

Am I missing something or it's doesn't support local caching management ?

Comment: You could try to do that with dependency service. It enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from Android. Fo this method, you could check the link. https://teamtreehouse.com/community/parse-local-datastore-pininbackground For depedency service, you could refer to the example from MS document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT How am I going to store **ParseObject** or **ParseQuery** in the device with dependency service ?